# Trace the phone number from the email sent

Tags: networking, email, iphone, ip-address

This question can be bizarre, but I just learnt that we can get the location from where the email is sent. Suppose the email is sent from a phone, say Iphone, will the ip address still point the correct location? Is the ip any different when it comes to mails sent through gprs?
I traced a location and it gave me the address. Is it the address of the sender himself, or does ip denote something else when sent through gprs?

Secondly, is it possible to get the phone number of the person, from the mail they sent from their phone? This acutally is very geeky and I would be really glad if someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, some email service providers, say Gmail, don't show X-Originating header in the email headers. So, it might not be possible to track the sender.

> Suppose the email is sent from a phone, say Iphone, will the ip address still point the correct location?

If at all you receive the header, the IP address will most probably provide the approximate location of the sender.

> Secondly, is it possible to get the phone number of the person, from the mail they sent from their phone?

No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Email and Phone and two different and unrelated technology.

For big companies who have their own IP block, you may be able to find the contact details(usually the abuse department) by doing an IP whois, but for individuals it is not possible even if you have their IP address. Add carrier grade NAT and it is even more complex.

The only possible way is to either ask for the contact info, or check if it is already there in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, Its not possible to get accurate geolocation from IP address. There are IP to Geolocation mapping databases available like MaxMind's GeoIP database. But IP addresses are constantly reallocated and no mappings are 100% accurate. For example MaxMind's GeoIP2 City database is

> 99.8% accurate on a country level, 80% accurate on a state level, 68% accurate on a city level for the US within a 50 kilometer radius.

Read more here [here](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-accuracy-comparison)